# C# : Replacing word in PDF with retaining space between replaced and its neighboring word

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

**This is what we want:**
We want to hide some specific words from PDF. This we are trying through searching and replacing word from PDF file. 
Also replaced occurrences need to be highlighted with black fore-colour. Both these replace and highlighting actions are for hiding/masking some information in PDF. Replace action will not let future users of PDF to guess about the original identity of masked words; and highlighting is used to give indication about masking.
If any such masked word is serving as link in PDF, it is expected to work as before.

**This is what we tried and the problem:** We tried this using Aspose.pdf for .net, and found that the single character used to replace all characters in searched word disturbs the formatting i.e original spacing between current and next word. 
**e.g.** if 'stackoverflow' is searched and replaced with 'x' for every character in searched word, it may overlap with next word in line if the character width is more after replacement; OR the spacing between searched word and next word appears to be widened if character spacing is lesser for replaced word.

Following situations could be expected:

If replaced word pushes next word in line to next line, all remaining contents in PDF should be moved according. This may result in addition of a new line in PDF and related impact on rest of PDF contents.

If replaced word frees up some pixel due to lesser character width, and allows next word to move towards left; it may result in words moving

**Please assist if there exists any way to adjust (auto adjust) this spacing between words after replacements using Aspose.pdf.**

**If this is not possible using Aspose, do you know any third party component which addresses this problem?**

**Or can this be achieved by creating a new pdf document from scratch using existing document with required replacements at runtime? And if this way is feasible, how to carry formatting in new pdf?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"If replaced word pushes next word in line to next line, all remaining contents in PDF should be moved according. This may result in addition of a new line in PDF and related impact on rest of PDF contents."* - This is something extremely difficult to do automatically (i.e. without a GUI to supervise and correct) in PDFs in general. PDFs being a format not meant for editing does not need to carry information about which glyphs belong together on a line or where margins starts, so often they don't.

Comment: An alternative approach is *redaction* which does not require reflowing existing content. While not trivial either, this is easier to implement in general than your approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
But is there a way so that contents from one PDF can be copied to a new one and replace the specific words at runtime.

Comment: Of course you can take one PDF and copy contents to another and on the way replace some stuff. But that won't help. If the source contains instructions "draw word1 at x1,y1; draw word2 at x2,y2", then replacing "word1" by "xxxxx" won't move "word2" a bit, whether or not the *y* coordinates are the same and *x2* is merely the width of "word1" plus a bit larger than *x1*...